# Why the maximum of Rényi entropy is not achieved for the uniform distribution?

Tags: r, probability, entropy

Given a discrete random variable $X$, which takes values in the alphabet $\mathcal {X}$ and is distributed according to $p:{\mathcal {X}}\to [0,1]$ the Shannon entropy is defined as:
$$\mathrm {H} (X):=-\sum _{x\in {\mathcal {X}}}p(x)\log p(x)$$
The Rényi entropy of order $\alpha$, where $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\alpha \neq 1$, is defined as
$$\mathrm {H} _{\alpha }(X)={\frac {1}{1-\alpha }}\log {\Bigg (}\sum _{i=1}^{N}p_{i}^{\alpha }{\Bigg )}$$
As argued in this question [Maximum value of Rényi entropy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615423/maximum-value-of-r%C3%A9nyi-entropy), the maximum of Rényi entropy is achieved for the uniform distribution, i.e.,
$$\mathrm {H} _{\alpha }(X)\leq \log N$$
Anyway, with $N=7$ and the following probabilities (in R code)

```
> dput(px)
c(0.0366339396854849, 0.0648970281629661, 0.0838483127482803, 
0.389068874772233, 0.32352515261566, 0.100990517511973, 0.00103617450340261
)
```

I obtained: $\mathrm {H} _{\alpha }(X)=2.594437$ but $\log N=1.94591$. How is it possible?

Comment: What $\alpha$ were you using for that $\mathrm {H} _{\alpha }(X)=2.594437$?

Comment: @Henry: $\alpha=1/5$

Comment: What does $N$ have to do with a uniform distribution, which is continuous?  Note that in your link the reference is to a "discrete" distribution.

Comment: Your calculation is erroneous.  $H_{1/5}(p)= 1.798327$ in your case.  Notice, too, that $H$ is a function of $p,$ not of $X.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to confirm whuber's calculation using R:

```
Halpha <- function(p,alpha){ 
  1/(1-alpha) * log(sum(p^alpha)) 
  }

px <- c(0.0366339396854849, 0.0648970281629661, 0.0838483127482803, 
   0.389068874772233, 0.32352515261566, 0.100990517511973, 0.00103617450340261)
N <- length(px)
Halpha(rep(1/N, N), 1/5)
# 1.94591
log(N)
# 1.94591
Halpha(px, 1/5)
# 1.798327
```

so a uniform distribution over seven possibilities gives a higher value for $H_{1/5}(p)$ than your `px` does